# How to create multiple elements in different places using DOM methods

Tags: javascript, css

So I used a loop to create what I thought would be multiple divs in the form of w3-cards but it seems to only create one how can I fix this, and can I specify an attribute that will put it in a specific place and or make it a specific size because currently it takes up the whole width of the screen. Also this snippet is in a much larger method where eventually I will send it a value for players, and yes I do know that this loop if it worked properly would only create three cards one player is exclude because they are a judge and don't need a card. Thanks again any help is appreciated.

```
var players = 4;
for(r = 0; r < players; r++){
  var r = document.createElement("div");
  r.className = "w3-card-4 w3-yellow w3-center";
  document.body.appendChild(r);
  r.innerHTML = "a meme";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop won't run through, because your condition very likely is only fulfilled one time. `r = 0; r < players; r++` because you reassign the value of `r`.
Try another variable for the counter like this:

```
var players = 4;
for(i = 0; i < players; i++){
  var r = document.createElement("div");
  r.className = "w3-card-4 w3-yellow w3-center";
  document.body.appendChild(r);
  r.innerHTML = "a meme";
}
```

Comment: Oh yea I cant believe I overlooked that haha I feel so stupid XD

Comment: @RichieZ It's just a second pair of eyes you need sometimes ;)
feel free to accept my answer, if you found it helpful